# randomforest R： why the print predict doesnt equal to the predict stored

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, random-forest

I am running randomforest model to predict blacklist.I get a real problem that I cant solve by myself.
My code is below.

```
library(xlsx)
library(randomForest) 
setwd('E:\\laolai')
rm(list=ls())
accepts <- read.xlsx('fuckdata.xlsx',sheetIndex = 1)
set.seed(10)
ind <- sample(2,nrow(accepts),replace=TRUE,prob=c(0.5,0.5))
train_data <- accepts[ind==1,]
test_data <- accepts[ind==2,]   
rf <- randomForest(formula,data=train_data,ntree=1500,na.action=na.roughfix)
plot(rf,main='randomforest')
print(rf)
source_3pred <- predict(rf,test_data)
plot(source_3pred,main='predict',xlab='trees',type='l')
```

Global Environment data:

```
accepts 3279obs. of 27 variables
test_data 1648 obs.of 27 variblss
train_data 1648 obs.of 27 variblss
```

Values:

```
source_3pred Named num [1:1648] NA NA NA NA NA.......
```

then

```
print(source_3pred)
```

get data from 2 to 3279.such as 3218 NA,3224 0.7609778.

Comment: You seem to have misconceptions about how random forests work.  With random forests, unlike most other machine learning methods, we don't explicitly use a training set of data.  Rather, we include _all_ data when building the model.  The reason for this is that random forests implicitly cross validates while building the model.

Comment: cause I ,first,python pandas it,then ,R,model it.how an annoy excel is.

Comment: So, I consider it wrong from the outset to have separate testing and training data, you should just be using your entire data set.

Comment: but how can I test the model.

Comment: I mean the accuracy,and peformance.

Answer (score 0):

The `randomForest` package comes with a function called `importance()`, which can compute two metrics of robustness for a random forest model built using the same package.  The first compares the prediction accuracy of each tree against the same tree but using a random permutation of the predictors.  The other method uses the Gini index/residual sum of squares to measure the decrease in node impurities for each split in the tree.

Here is a code sample of how you might access the importance of your random forest model:

```
rf <- randomForest(formula, data=train_data, ntree=1500, na.action=na.roughfix,
                   importance=TRUE)
# for permutation measure of accuracy
importance(rf, type=1)

# for split measure of accuracy
importance(rf, type=2)
```